# Using includes() method when having only one element in an array is it efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does the below code blocks vary in performance especially when the array has only one element?

```
myArray.includes(anElement);
```

and

```
myArray.length === 1 && myArray[0] === anElement
```

Please tell which is a good coding practice and also tell about any performance issues in the above two scenarios.

Comment: They do different things? If your array is guaranteed to only have one element, the `.length` check would be redundant, if not, then the second is false if it has more. This reeks of premature optimization anyways.

Comment: The performance difference if there's any shoudn't be a problem.
The best solution will be the one that is easier to read.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: unless it's in a tight loop on a mission-critical section, i wouldn't worry about the perf difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the array has only one element - the only difference is the length check. So if you are running this in a loop for a long time - probably you will see a difference because of that.

But the problem here is that you should not assume that the array has only one element unless you checked it previously, then it's the same.

If the array may contain more than one element, then the logic between these two is different and the comparison doesn't make sense.

Bottom line - to have them with the same logic you will do the same work. So just make it readable as @Xion 14 suggested.